# Finance mathematics for high schools - book recommendation

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for books of Finance mathematics for high schools with exercises and problems. Please, could you recommend me some books?
Thanks.

Comment: Like compound interest and that sort of thing? I just want to make sure you mean personal finance, and not the stuff you'd learn to get a job in finance.

Comment: yes, compound interest (not university level).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [The Mathematics of Investment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1179122119) by William L. Hart?

[image: The Mathematics of Investment by William L. Hart]

From the Amazon description:

> This is a reproduction of a book published before 1923. This book may have occasional imperfections such as missing or blurred pages, poor pictures, errant marks, etc. that were either part of the original artifact, or were introduced by the scanning process. We believe this work is culturally important, and despite the imperfections, have elected to bring it back into print as part of our continuing commitment to the preservation of printed works worldwide. We appreciate your understanding of the imperfections in the preservation process, and hope you enjoy this valuable book.

Answer (score 1):

Or how about [Schaum's Outline of Mathematics of Finance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071756051) by Robert Brown and Petr Zima?

[image: Schaum's Outline of Mathematics of Finance by Robert Brown and Petr Zima]